# How to deny a http request (throw some code error)

Tags: python, api, flask, request

Here's my code, i need to change the "BLOCKED" return, to a legit request deny, how can i do it?

```
@app.route('/api/echo-json', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT'])
def add():

    data = request.get_json()
    dt_string = datetime.now()
    objeto = Requisicao(data,dt_string)

    if len(lista)<2:
        lista.append(objeto.id)
        lista.append(objeto.hora)
        return 'PASS'

    for i in range(0,len(lista),2):
        if lista[i] == objeto.id and objeto.hora < lista[i+1] + timedelta(seconds=10):
            return 'BLOCKED'

    else:
        lista.append(objeto.id)
        lista.append(objeto.hora)
        return 'PASS'
```

Comment: Do you mean a HTTP error code? Which one?

Comment: Yes, the 403 Forbidden

Answer (score 0):

You want to return an error as opposed to a usually success? something like this could work:

```
return jsonify(success=False, errors=errors), 500
```

Alternatively you can raise an error in Python? I would look here

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Right , your error here would be whatever the actual error is . For example before this you can add errors = ‘blocked’

Answer (score 0):

You can just return a tuple where the first item is the message, and the second item is the HTTP error code.

I'm not sure from your code what kind of response you want to return, but 400 (Bad Request) might be suitable for an API. Here's the full list: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

```
@app.route('/bad_request'):
    return jsonify({}), 400
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to return an HTTP error like 400. See the other answer for a link to HTTP error codes. A variation on that answer, closer to your code:

```
@app.route('/api/echo-json', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT'])
def add():
    ...
    if ...:
        ...
        return 'PASS'

    for ...:
        if ...:
            return 'BLOCKED', 403

    ...
```

Comment: But denies the request? Or just return the 400?

Comment: Simply replace 400 with the error code you need (edited accordingly)